# Make groups of GPS Coordinates based on a given Path

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary, math, gps

I have the next situation: I have a set of GPS data (lat, lng and datetime) and also a set of GPS data that creates a Path. I'd like to split the set of GPS data that has a timestamp in groups based on that Path. The first set of data belongs to the Path, and it should be spplited in the amount of times that the GPS coordinates has traveled all the path. For example: In the first set I have GPS location from 0 to 20, from 0 to 5 the path has been traveled, from 6 to 15 has been traveled again and then from 16 to 20 again. So, I expect 3 groups, how can I do that? Exists some algorithm for this? I've been thinking of aggregation and some math models, but I want to check first in exists some solution for not reinvent the wheel.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not that easy to understand your question, but I guess https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching is what you want to do first in order to match the first set (trajectory) to the second set (road network?).  Afterwards splitting the trajectory should be easy.

Comment: Do you know for sure that the data _always_ corresponds to one or more **complete** traversals of the path? Or can there be partial traversals (starting and/or ending at some intermediate point), non-path data points, etc? Also, I assume that even when the points in the data correspond to traversals of the path, they do not need to be exactly one of the points in the path, right?